# Powershell editor not giving me any errors but java isn't being uninstalled

Tags: java, powershell

```
#Uninstaller
IF((test-path 
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
    {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0}') -eq 'true')
{
    start-process -wait -filepath "c:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -
        argumentlist "/X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /quiet /l* 
        c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt"

    #-RedirectedStandardOutput c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt -
        RedirectStandardError 
        c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt -NoNewWindow
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Application not found"
}
```

This purpose of this program is to uninstall java using a deployment console for our school. I already have a working installer that I wrote in the deployment console but I'm trying to switch the uninstaller over to a powershell script. Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my code? The code compiles and runs fine but java is still installed on the computer afterwards.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the test-path is returning true and finding the location? In my experience the registry handles test-path poorly and will only work up until finding a value in which you then need to use get-childitem and search using -match.  It may be best for you to perhaps capture the error output using $variable = Start-Process then checking the $Variable.ExitCode to see what the error code is that Java is throwing back, then researching the error code.

Comment: Maybe the missing space in `"/X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /quiet /l* 
        c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt"` should be `"/X {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /quiet /l* 
        c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt"`

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: @Moerwald no that wouldn't be it, it looks like he's pulled that string straight from the 'quiet uninstall' key in the registry and just added on the logging function. In the registry it actually shows as /x{blahblahblah}. But good idea at least. Keen eye!

Comment: I can try your idea @Random206. I haven't ever scripted in Powershell before yesterday and I am trying to create this script based off of the uninstall script an ex-employee wrote for a different program.

Comment: Ok, no problems, we all start somewhere, best thing to do is open the powershell ise (Start powershell console as admin then type in Powershell ISE and hit enter). From there in the script editor area (top part) try type in $Return = start-process -wait -filepath "msiexec" -argumentlist "/X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /q /L c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt" then on the line below, type Write-Host $Return.ExitCode once you've done that you can highlight each line and hit F8 to execute only that line. Run each line and you'll get the exit code. If $Return.ExitCode is empty, it's a syntax issue

Comment: Actually you could change the /q switch to /passive for a more visual experience of the uninstall while performing your troubleshooting as it may not be an issue with the script but rather something from Java, which may be stopping the uninstallation from executing.

Comment: So I tried looking at the If conditional to see if it is even finding the string I'm looking for and the conditional returns a true so I know Powershell is finding it. What is this line doing? "start-process -wait -filepath "c:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -
        argumentlist "/X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /quiet /l* 
        c:\csg-bin\JavaGUIDs.txt""